# Android correct location for hierarchical file list

Tags: android

I have a simple app which needs to display 1 of many text files (DB is no an option currently)

Where is the best place to put this collection of text files? I am guessing "Assets", but am unsure.

Comment: I would say it depends on what kind of files you have. I think if they are images for instance, maybe they would be better in the drawable folder?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The "Assets" folder was the best place I found.